# Browser refresh when removing routerLink

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having an issue with Angular 2+. So I'm dynamically creating tabs in a specific page on my app and those tabs can also be removed by the user when clicking close tab ('x'), imagine something similar with the opened files on an IDE or text editor.

I have my tabs saved on an array and when the user removes one, I do a splice on the array, the tab gets removed from the view but the browser refreshes.

Each tab has a routerLink so that we can navigate between tabs and on my module I have something like tab/:id.

I'm using an `<a>` tag not a button so it's not the type="submit" issue.

I tried removing the routerLink from the tabs and it doesn't refresh so I figured it's a problem with routerLink but I can't figure out more.

Does anyone knows what the problem could be? 
Any solution?

Thanks advance!

Comment: You should add some code to your question to paint a better picture of what you're doing, otherwise all we can say is 'huh, sounds like it should work'.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an `event.preventDefault()` to the click event of the elements(tabs) that had routerLink.